# Python: linear __getitem__ for a pair of list of lists

Tags: python, class

I currently have a class which stores a list of lists. The inner lists are not of the same length. I made the class subscriptable with the following code (possibly not the best way of doing this, and perhaps overly fancy).

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #
        self.instructions = []

        # for demo purposes
        self.instructions.append([0, 1, 2])
        self.instructions.append([3, 4, 5, 6])
        self.instructions.append([7, 8])

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        if ind >= 0:
            iterator = self.instructions.__iter__()
            compare = int.__gt__
            inc = int.__add__
        else:
            iterator = reversed(self.instructions)
            compare = int.__le__
            inc = int.__sub__

        s = 0
        for tp in iterator:
            L = len(tp)
            if compare(inc(s, L), ind):
                return tp[ind-s]
            else:
                s = inc(s, L)
        else:
            raise IndexError('index out of range')
```

This works. For instance

```py
>>> x = MyClass()
>>> x[5]
5
>>> x[-5]
4
```

Now, I need to modify the class so it now stores two list of lists. The two lists are `instructions` and `annotations`, and both have the same length. But `len(instructions[i])` does not have to equal `len(annotations[i])`.

```py
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #
        self.instructions = []
        self.annotations = []

        # for demo purposes
        self.instructions.append([0, 1, 2])
        self.instructions.append([5, 6, 7, 8])
        self.instructions.append([12, 13])
        
        self.annotations.append([3, 4])
        self.annotations.append([9, 10, 11])
        self.annotations.append([14, 15, 16])

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        pass
```

I want to make this subscriptable, with the order of elements oscillating between the `instructions` sublists and the `annotations` sublists. The demo data indicates the subscripting order. I want

```py
>>> y = NewClass()
>>> y[9]
9
>>> y[-4]
13
```

What's an efficient way of doing this?

I could write a solution where I alternatively iterate through the two sublists. But I feel like I am straying far from the correct solution. I am also looking for a non-for-loop solution as I am dealing with long lists.

Comment: **stop using dunder methods like this: `compare = int.__gt__`** use the `operator` module

Comment: Just a suggestion, I think you'd simplify your logic a lot by simply keeping track of your total length, then calculating the positive index from the negative index.

Comment: What, exactly, is `__getitem__` supposed to return? Are you just trying to chain the sublists together into one flat iterable?

Comment: Will `instructions` and `annotations` always have the same length?

Comment: How long are your actual lists (both the outer and the inner lists)?

Comment: Will you modify the lists (inner and outer) after creating the `MyClass` instance (in particular, between multiple calls of the `__getitem__` method?

Comment: Btw why do you have such split lists anyway?

Comment: What do you mean with "linear" in the title?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, `instructions` and `annotations` have the same length. But the sublists don't. The total items can exceed 100k. The lists are appended to, by user operations and can change length between different calls to __getitem__.

Comment: Total items is good to know, but it makes a big difference whether you have many short lists or only a few but long lists.

Comment: @KellyBundy The library is a simulation library where users have wide liberty in how they populate the data structures, depending on what they are simulating. So I want reasonably equal performance for both many short lists and few long lists, as as not to annoy the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While your implementation is nice, I would like to share my own way for iterating using `chain.from_iterable`. Because basically we're chaining the items whether from the beginning or at the end.

##### For one list:

The only part that needs explanation is `map(reversed, reversed(self.instructions))`. We not only need to reverse the whole list, but also the individual sublists.

```py
from itertools import chain

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instructions = [
            [0, 1, 2],
            [3, 4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8],
        ]

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        if ind >= 0:
            chunks = self.instructions
            range_parameter = ind + 1
        else:
            chunks = map(reversed, reversed(self.instructions))
            range_parameter = abs(ind)

        iterator = chain.from_iterable(chunks)

        try:
            for _ in range(range_parameter):
                n = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            raise IndexError("index out of range")

        return n

x = MyClass()
print(x[5])
print(x[-5])
```

##### For two lists:

Since you said we need to oscillate, `zip` is the right tool for that. When `ind` is positive it's straightforward. We zip them and use `chain.from_iterable` two times because otherwise it gives us individual sub-lists.

If `ind` is negative, we need two `reversed()` before zipping. One for outer lists, and one for sublists.

```py
from itertools import chain

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instructions = [
            [0, 1, 2],
            [5, 6, 7, 8],
            [12, 13],
        ]

        self.annotations = [
            [3, 4],
            [9, 10, 11],
            [14, 15, 16],
        ]

    def __getitem__(self, ind):
        if ind >= 0:
            chunks = zip(self.instructions, self.annotations)
            range_parameter = ind + 1
        else:
            chunks = zip(
                map(reversed, reversed(self.annotations)),
                map(reversed, reversed(self.instructions)),
            )
            range_parameter = abs(ind)

        iterator = chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(chunks))

        try:
            for _ in range(range_parameter):
                n = next(iterator)
        except StopIteration:
            raise IndexError("index out of range")

        return n

x = MyClass()
print(x[9])
print(x[-4])
```

Comment: If you're going to chain into one iterator of elements, just use islice then instead of your loop. But I don't think chaining into an iterator of all elements is a good idea anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Your was the best among the working answers. I have accepted yours as the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

The standard balance between storage cost and runtime cost for random access into the (non-stored) concatenation of several arrays is to store a table of the **offsets** of the beginning of each list (*i.e.*, the sum of the length of every list before it) and use **binary search** on that table:

```
import itertools
import bisect

class Index:
    def __init__(self,ll):
        self.ll = ll
        self.oo = list(itertools.accumulate(map(len,ll), initial=0))

    def __getitem__(self, i):
        if i < 0:
            i += self.oo[-1]
        j = bisect.bisect(self.oo,i)
        if not 0 < j <= len(self.ll):
            raise IndexError
        return self.ll[j-1][i-self.oo[j-1]]

    def __iter__(self):
        return itertools.chain.from_iterable(self.ll)

# Example:
i = Index(
  [[9,1,7],
   [3,0],
   [],
   [4,4,4,2]]
)
assert i[4]==0 and i[8]==2
```

The `j-1` is because the initial 0 causes an `i` of 0 to be assigned the insertion point of 1.  You can omit the `,initial=0` (and in fact the last element of `self.oo` as well) at the cost of more complicated code for the edge/error cases.  `__iter__` is provided because it is asymptotically **faster** than indexing with successive integers, each of which must be subjected to the binary search even though usually the same sublist will be found.

Obviously extending this to support the **interleaving** of two lists (of equal length) is trivial: sum the interleaved lengths and then use `divmod(j-1,2)` to obtain the index into a list and the selection between the two lists (respectively).

Comment: I took the liberty of editing your code to be in line with python conventions

Comment: Also, can you elaborate on the interleaving case? Because that is the crux of the actual question

Comment: Binary search makes me do an "oh, of course". Would you kindly write down the two list solution as that is what I am specifically asking for? Thanks.

Comment: @AbdullahKhalid You'll have to somehow update the offsets table for your changes to the lists, though. You might want to look into how [SortedList](https://grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sortedlist.html) does this.

Comment: @AbdullahKhalid: If you are changing the sublists (with or without two lists of sublists), that's quite a [different problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree), so we have to resolve that first.

Answer (score 0):

here is my idea, for the 2 list version

first we define a funtion to alternate between lists

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def alternate(*iterables: "list[list[Any]]") -> "Iterator[list[Any]]":
    for group in zip_longest(*iterables):
        for it in group:
            if it is not None:
                yield it
```

like that in can alternate between any number of your lists

now for the class

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.instructions = [
            [0, 1, 2],
            [5, 6, 7, 8],
            [12, 13],
        ]

        self.annotations = [
            [3, 4],
            [9, 10, 11],
            [14, 15, 16],
        ]
        
    def __len__(self):
        return sum(map(len,alternate(self.instructions, self.annotations)))
    
    def __getitem__(self, index:int ):
        size = len(self)
        if index >= 0:
            if index >= size:
                raise IndexError(index)
        else:
            new_index = size + index
            if 0 <= new_index < size:
                index = new_index
            else:
                raise IndexError(index)
        for item in alternate(self.instructions, self.annotations):
            n = len(item)
            if 0 <= index < n:
                return item[index]
            index -= n
        raise RuntimeError("this should not happens")

test = MyClass()
print(test[9])
print(test[-4])
```

I defined a len which is the sum of all the length of the sublist, and use that in the `__getitem__` to first determinate if the input index is valid or not, and for the negative case first calculate the positive version of the index and check if its correct.

With that done, and given that the sublist aren't of the same size, then simple going in a loop for each of the sublist and if the index fall in its range return that otherwise subtract the size of that sublist and go to the next.

and because python is cool like that you get for free that your class is iterable (just by having and `__getitem__` that take interger values) and reversible (by also having a `__len__`)

```
>>> list(test)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
>>> list(reversed(test))
[16, 15, 14, 13, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

alternatively you can use the *nth* recipe

```
from itertools import islice
   
def nth(iterable, n, default=None):
    "Returns the nth item or a default value"
    return next(islice(iterable, n, None), default)
```

(or from the `more_itertools` third party library)

and then alongside `itertools.chain` you can change the final loop in getitem for `return nth(chain.from_iterable(alternate(self.instructions, self.annotations)), index)` given that we already check that the index fall in range

Comment: That free iteration is very slow, though.

Comment: @KellyBundy sure, but you can always make your own if necessary, there is only so much that python can do for you to give you free stuff

Answer (score -1):

Here is my approach:

```py
import itertools


class NewClass:
    def __init__(self):
        #
        self.instructions = []
        self.annotations = []

        # for demo purposes
        self.instructions.append([0, 1, 2])
        self.instructions.append([5, 6, 7, 8])
        self.instructions.append([12, 13])
        
        self.annotations.append([3, 4])
        self.annotations.append([9, 10, 11])
        self.annotations.append([14, 15, 16])
        
    def __iter__(self):
        zipped = itertools.zip_longest(self.instructions, self.annotations, fillvalue=[])
        for sub_lists in zipped:
            yield from itertools.chain.from_iterable(sub_lists)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        flat = list(self)
        return flat[key]
```

#### Notes

- I created the `__iter__` method, which let the caller iterates through the object like this:

  ```
    x = NewClass()
    for e in x:
        print(e)
  ```
- The `__getitem__` is built upon `__iter__`
- About the `zipped` data: Conceptually, you can view this as

  ```
    [
        [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]],          # This is a sub_lists
        [[5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]],  # a sub_lists
        ...
    ]
  ```
- The expression `itertools.chain.from_iterable(sub_lists)` basically flatten a `sub_lists` from `[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4]]` to `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`
- This solution works for an arbitrary number of lists, not just 2.

#### Update

I fixed up the `__getitem__` to handle negative index at the cost of performance. I'm too lazy to create a solution which is more efficient.

Comment: this doesn't handle negative indicea

Comment: Updated to handle negative index

Comment: Creating the flattened list on every indexing operation is, I would argue, a rather large "cost of performance", since one could just store that list once and then index it directly.

Answer (score -1):

If the two concatenated lists are the same size, you can use something like this:

```
div, mod = divmod(ind, 2)
if mod:
    return get_item(second_list, div)
else:
    return get_item(first_list, div)
```